# What was the aerial chase scene plane in 'Murder in the Clouds'?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I spotted this aircraft (tail number **NC-406N**) in an aerial chase scene in the movie [*Murder in the Clouds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_in_the_Clouds) (1934) on Turner Classic Movies.

It appears to be a [Travel Air D-4000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_Air_2000). Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

NC-406N would likely have become N-406N if reregistered or transferred. Since none of the [52 Travel Air 4000's registered](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Mms_Results.aspx?Mmstxt=2621802&conVal=0&PageNo=1) nor any of the [6 Travel Air D-4000s](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Mms_Results.aspx?Mmstxt=2621808&conVal=0&PageNo=1) still have the NC prefix, I'm guessing this is what has happened.

[Tail N406N](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=N-406N) is listed by the FAA as a D-4000 Registered from 1991 on. If this is what you meant, then yes it is correct. Additionally, the wiki page for the movie does list a "Travel Air Speedwings" [sic] as the aircraft used in the production of the movie. I've not been able to verify if N406N is actually a speedwing vs the other models of Travel Air but a more knowledgeable expert might do so with the serial number: 1337.